# Recommended way to mirgate old Android app data for API 33

Tags: android, upgrade, compatibility

I have an old Android app that was targeting < API29. It still uses `< sdcard >/somefolder` to store files. ie. There are versions running on user's devices that still use directories that they will not have access to under API 33.

Clearly, I need to cater for users who upgrade the app to the latest version using API33.

Under API33, I can not even read all the files in the old app folder; though I can access media files.

Ideally, I'd like to just move those files on App startup.

The only solution I can currently think of is to get the app to start without its old files, then ask the user (using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) to grant access to the old directory (if I can find it), then move the files and restart the app. Is this really the best/only way??? I was hoping for an 'invisible' solution, (edit for clarity:) and looking for a low-cost one, eg, I do not want to completely re-code the app to use SAF everywhere it uses `java.io.File` (which still works in 'acceptable' directories).

**Please Note:** This is NOT a question about the recommended way to access files in API33, it is a question about how to MIGRATE the data of an existing, already-installed, no-longer-compliant app to the new rules.

Comment: You should use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user pick your old directory.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant when I said, "The only solution I can currently think of is to get the app to start without its old files, then ask the user to grant access to the old directory". I will clarify the question. I was hoping to upgrade silently, if at all possible.

Comment: The user picks the directory and then you have access to all old files using SAF. There is no reason to move them

Comment: I'm looking for compatibility with existing code which uses java.io.File (and have clarified the question further); sadly Google did not implement a File-like interface in SAF, so it's a choice to completely recode ALL file access OR move the files to 'acceptable' directories, in which old code will work...AFAICT. Like I said, I had hoped for a means to just seemlessly migrate...but now suspect that's not possible.

Comment: You can, after the user selected the old directory, create a new directory in public directory Documents and copy your files to it using java.io.File. After that keep using java.io.File. Only the path is a bit different. You read your old files with SAF. You create the new files in the old way. With SAF you can also delete the old directory. A one time action.

Comment: That is, I think, exactly what I suggested as the undesirable solution in my original question: "The only solution I can currently think of is to get the app to start without its old files, then ask the user (using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) to grant access to the old directory (if I can find it), then move the files and restart the app."